# How do I show row numbers in JqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, numbers, row, line

How do I show row numbers in JqGrid ?
My 'grid.js' is:

```
    grid : {
            'url':'cs?action=getGridContent&gridType=1001',
            'col_names':['№','Qeydiyyat nömrəsi','Qeydiyyat tarixi','İmzalayan şəxs' , 'İcraçı şöbə','','',''],
            'col_model': [
                {name: 'r', index: 'r', sorttype: 'int', width:'10'},
                {name: 'col2', index: 'col2', sorttype: 'text', width:'40' },
                {name: 'col3', index: 'col3', sorttype: 'date', width:'30' },
                {name: 'col4', index: 'col4', sorttype: 'text', width:'35' },
                {name: 'col5', index: 'col5', sorttype: 'text', width:'30' },
                {name: 'docid', index: 'docid', sorttype: 'date', width:'10',hidden:true },
                {name: 'doctypeid', index: 'doctypeid', sorttype: 'date',     width:'10',hidden:true } ,
                {name: 'docclass', index: 'docclass', sorttype: 'date', width:'10',hidden:true }
            ],
            sortname: 'col3',
            sortorder: "desc"
        }
```

I can't add automatic number per row.

Comment: Please describe about your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should first read the official documentation with [the list of supported options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options). The option which shows row numbers is

```
rownumbers: true
```